# ¿Cómo finalizar un release con git flow sin escribir un mensaje?

Tags: git

Estoy tratando de automatizar el `release` de un módulo con `jenkins` y parte de ello es hacer un `release` de un determinado `módulo` o programa.

Estoy usando [git flow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow) para hacer los `releases` pero me topé con el problema de que **me pide un mensaje a la hora de finalizar dicho `release` y por eso no puedo automatizarlo.**

Déjenme explicarles mejor con un ejemplo:

Inicio mi `release`:

```
git flow release start 1.0.0
//...luego hago otros pasos
```

Finalizo mi release:

```
git flow release finish 1.0.0
```

**Acá quiero que NO me salga la siguiente pantalla:**

```
//Línea en blanco para que yo escriba mi mensaje
#
# Write a tag message
# Lines starting with '#' will be ignored.
```

Cuando escribo el mensaje y guardo, todo sale bien pero quiero alguna forma de poner algún mensaje por defecto o dejarlo en blanco. ¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo?

Comment: Segun veo en [aqui](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/pull/287) para que funcione la version de gitflow-avh, hay que agregar al entorno `export GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT=no` pero no lo he probado

Answer (score 1):

Puede que esto sea lo que busca ->

git flow release finish 1.0.0 `-m 'Su mensaje'`

git flow release finish `-m 'Su mensaje'` 1.0.0

[git flow release finish [-FsumpkS]](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/blob/develop/git-flow-release#L47)

el de [-m](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/blob/develop/git-flow-release#L194)

https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/blob/develop/git-flow-release#L194
https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/blob/develop/git-flow-release#L251

---

el de [-f](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/blob/develop/git-flow-release#L195) mensajeFile

https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/blob/develop/git-flow-release#L195
https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/blob/develop/git-flow-release#L252

Comment: Gracias pero lo he probado y no me ha funcionado.

Comment: ha usado las dos maneras? le arroja algun error en el terminal que diga error de sintaxis o algo asi? Saludos

Comment: `-m` antes y después de la versión, `-f` antes y después también, y nada, abre la ventana para escribir el mensaje con el editor por defecto.

Comment: @Gepser pues es raro, igual puede notificarlo como bug, igual de serlo lo corrigen y si se hace de otra manera, le digan como es.

Comment: El repositorio ya no lo mantienen desde el 2012. Me he pasado a este otro https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow-avh/ y he probado lo que dices, acepta el mensaje como parámetro pero igual abre la ventana del editor de texto y pone el mensaje que le he pasado. Casi casi pero no soluciona mi problema.